# Center Bing Maps V7 around Array of Points

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

In my Bing Maps V6.3 implementation, I was able to center my map around an array of points using the following code.

```
map.SetMapView(latlonArray);
if (map.GetZoomLevel() > 10) {
    map.SetZoomLevel(10);
};
```

This code does not work in Bing Maps V7, and I can't find an alternative on the web.

Note: latlonArray is simply being populated as such

```
var increment = 0;
$.each(json_object, function () {
    latlonArray[increment] = new VELatLong(this.lat, this.lon);
    increment = ++increment;
});
```

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107536/bing-virtual-earth-7-0-calculate-area/7110178#7110178

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [LocationRect.fromLocations()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427621.aspx) method. It accepts an array of locations, and returns a rectangle.

also: For v7, the new type representing a latitude/longitude location is Microsoft.Maps.Location , not VELatLong.

Comment: Nice.  I was always keeping track of min/max lat/lon when drawing results.  Depending on how many pins you have, that may be faster.